# Drupal 8 field collection – how to get raw value of a taxonomy field from field.html.twig?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8, drupal-field-collection

I've got a node with a field collection, which contains a taxonomy field.
I'd like to get the raw value or ID of this taxonomy field, to use in a conditional statement and provide different markup for different values.

e.g.:

```
{% set imageType = item.content.field_image_type|raw %}

{% if imageType == 'web-desktop' %}
    // markup A
{% else %}
    // markup B
{% endif %}
```

The variable works correctly, in that I am getting the expected output when rendering it, however the test always returns false.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you verifying the variable? Did u try `{{ dump(imageType)  }}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply; have just dumped, and it seems the returned value is an array. Here's the output:

`array(2) { ["#plain_text"]=> string(11) "web-desktop" ["#cache"]=> array(3) { ["tags"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "taxonomy_term:67" } ["contexts"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "user.permissions" } ["max-age"]=> int(-1) } }`

Comment: And that is where the answer lay! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DarkBee for the tip, I dumped the variable and used `['#plain_text']` from the output; the test now works as expected. For reference, here's the code:

```
{% set imageType = item.content.field_image_type[0]['#plain_text'] %}
```